# Поиск по словосочетанию SearchView & ArrayList & ListView

Tags: java, android, android-search-view

Использую `SearchView` и стандартный адаптер `ArrayAdapter`, с помощью `adapter.getFilter().filter(newText)`;  произвожу поиск, но стандартный поиск у метода `getFilter` работает только по первому слову, то есть он легко выведет 2 вариант по запросу "Авто" но по запросу "Автомобильное кре" вывод будет пустой, что делать?
Предполагаю что нужно использовать в адаптере `.contains` но свой адаптер не сумею сделать, есть идеи как поступить?

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

  static SearchView searchView;
  static ListView listView;
  static ArrayList < String > list;
  ArrayAdapter < String > adapter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.version_1_activity_menu);

    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.svmenu);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);
    list = new ArrayList < > ();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.add("Справка");
    list.add("Деталь для станка");
    list.add("Чайник");
    list.add("Автомобильное кресло");
    list.add("Автомобильное кресло премиум");
    list.add("Вопросы");

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {


      @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
          adapter.getFilter().filter(newText); // ТуТ
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
```